# Select specific tables

Tags: sql-server

Hi I wan't to select specific tables by using a query I found. I can use it to select all the tables but wan't to use the query to select a few .
I'm using this query:

```
SELECT t.TABLE_SCHEMA AS [Parent], 
t.TABLE_NAME AS [Object],
t.COLUMN_NAME AS [Type], 
cd.value AS [Description]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t
INNER JOIN syscolumns c
ON c.name = t.COLUMN_NAME
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties cd
ON cd.major_id = c.id
AND cd.minor_id = c.colid
AND cd.name = 'MS_Description'
ORDER BY t.TABLE_NAME, t.COLUMN_NAME
```

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Add a where clause to limit what you get back...  If the question is in some way more complex than that you need to explain why

Comment: Thanks, it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added where clause, you can change where clause parameter if you want.

```
SELECT t.TABLE_SCHEMA AS [Parent], 
    t.TABLE_NAME AS [Object],
    t.COLUMN_NAME AS [Type], 
    cd.value AS [Description]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS t
    INNER JOIN syscolumns c
    ON c.name = t.COLUMN_NAME
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties cd
    ON cd.major_id = c.id
    AND cd.minor_id = c.colid
    AND cd.name = 'MS_Description'
WHERE t.TABLE_NAME LIKE '%your search%'
ORDER BY t.TABLE_NAME, t.COLUMN_NAME
```

Another query you can use:

```
SELECT distinct TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%your table%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `WHERE` clause to limit what you get back, this is just standard SQL